# Make PC w/ Bluetooth fake Keyboard + mouse for other computer?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, remote

Is there a way to have my PC talk to my laptop and have it send Keyboard commands?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I believe this is possible with something called Synergy.  It lets you use your internet(or LAN) connection to control multiple computers with one mouse and keyboard.

Here is a link : http://synergy-project.org/

I haven't used it in the manner your suggesting, but I believe it should work.

I haven't heard of a solution that uses Bluetooth to connect to multiple systems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've used Synergy. It works pretty well. Connecting is slightly confusing, though- I never remember which one is considered the "client" and which one is the "server". There's a wrapper GUI called "QuickSynergy" for it if that package doesn't get installed by default.